# Difference between expected variance and variance

Tags: statistics

What is the difference between:

$\sigma^2 = E[(X - \mu)^2]$

and

$\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum(X - \mu)^2)}{N-1}$  or $N$ for variance

Can someone explain what is meant by the expected value of the variance and how it differs from the (sample) variance?

Comment: $E[(X-\mu)^2]$ is the true variance of the random variable $X$. The sample variance is just an estimate of the true variance based on samples of $X$.

Comment: @bames Okay, but why is there no denominator or summation? What defines a true variance?

Comment: The variance of $X$ is *defined as* $\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]$. The denominator of the sample variance arises from the fact that you took $N$ samples to estimate the variance. Are you familiar with how the estimator $\frac{\sum_i (X_i-\mu)^2}{N-1}$ is derived?

Comment: No, I have not. What I am wondering is if this expected value is just jargon, or a notation used to generalize the the sample/population variance, since no sample is known because it can be any arbitrary number. In other words I am wondering is if this expected value has any meaning in practice rather than in theory - in practice we are always working with a sample size.

Comment: For a real random variable $Z$, the expected value of $Z$ is $$\Bbb E [Z] = \int_{\Bbb R} zf(z)\;dz$$ where $f(z)$ is the probability density function for $Z$. When you are performing an experiment and you want to know if your statistical model for the data is close to reality, it would be useful to know what the true parameters (e.g., mean, variance) are for your model.